# Is there way to wirelessly connect a arduino drone‘s camera?

Tags: wireless, camera, stream

Is there way to wirelessly connect a arduino drone‘s camera and stream to a set device from 10 km away?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino.SE. Questions starting with "Is there a way" are usually very broad and sometimes difficult to answer. You may receive more and better answers if you expand your question by describing, what you have tried already and how you (not) succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the most common solution for streaming low latency drone video, called FPV. You basically connect an AV video output from a camera to a transmitter and use a receiver on the ground to receive the AV video. After this you can connect it to any AV display (or a usb AV decoder if you want to use a computer) and you'll get an almost real time video feed of what is happening on your drone. To get long range you would need to buy a powerful transmitter, good receiver and decent antennas for bout of them. You can find different configurations for different ranges online.

Answer (score 0):

Most (commonly available) RF links' communication distance is more limited than that (10 Km). If your flying locations are within a cell service area, a cell radio aboard the drone will probably give you the most universally available connection. Note that your streaming rate may vary with the location and cell congestion at that particular time, and may sometimes be limited, especially for video.